# If the charts comprising an atlas are disjoint, is the smoothness of transition functions trivial?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Suppose we have a manifold $M$ and an atlas consisting of two charts $U_1 , U_2$ which are disjoint. Does this cause a problem or is our life easier? I would guess that smoothness follows vacuously but I want to make sure.

Comment: Smoothness follows vacuously, but this only happens if $M$ is the disjoint union of these charts. This shouldn't be true in any interesting examples.

Comment: Thank you - my particular case is the lines in $\mathbb R^2$, choosing the sets of lines with nonnegative and strictly negative slope respectively.

Comment: That manifold is connected so it can't admit an atlas consisting of two disjoint charts. If you check carefully you'll see that the subspace of lines with non-negative slope isn't open.